# cpan fails because it can't verify cpan.org's SSL certificate

Tags: perl, cpan

I upgraded perl from perl 5.18.2 to perl 5.36.0, and now many modules are missing. When I try to install the module using CPAN, I am getting errors.

For ex:

```
 cpan YAML::XS
```

It gave me the following error:

```
 ERROR: cannot verify cpan.org's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Let's 
 Encrypt/CN=R3’:
 Issued certificate has expired.
 To connect to cpan.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I tried following to resolve error:

```
 install -y ca-certificates
```

and

```
 update-ca-certificates
```

But none worked for me.

Now, what should I do, due to this I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: CPAN's HTTPS cert was modified about 10 minutes ago and my browser has no problems connecting. This looks like a problem that their end that they have now fixed.

Comment: I again tried installing the module, but I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Then the most likely explanation is that your computer's clock is wrong.

Comment: After correcting clock, I am still having same issue

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin says in a comment, this seems to have been a temporary glitch that has been fixed now.

But if you're using your system Perl, then it's probably safer to install modules using `yum` anyway.

```
$ yum install 'perl(YAML::XS)'
```

**Update:** I used `yum` because that's what you used in your example and that led me to believe that you're using Centos or some other Red Hat derivative. On newer versions of Red Hat and its children, `yum` is replaced by `dnf`. If you tell us which distribution you're using, we can tell you how to install pre-built packages of CPAN modules.

Comment: Yum is not currently installed. To install it, I need administrator's rights, which I don't have. Can you please suggest any alternate solution?

Comment: I used cpan <module_name> to install the module and for the certificate, I used the above-mentioned 2 commands, but none worked.

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi: I don't know which distribution uses a program called `install` to install packages. So I'm not sure how I can help you any more.

Comment: can you please help me out with module installation using cpan? Can you tell me why isn't it working? Are you also using perl5.36?

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi: It works fine for me (I'm using Perl 5.34 - but that's not going to make any difference). The problem is with your environment. You need to talk it through with whoever runs your network.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04, is it causing the problem?

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi: Possibly. That version has been unsupported since 2019 (unless you've paid for extended support). It's possible that you're not getting the necessary security certificate updates.

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi: For Ubuntu, you could try installing the package with `sudo apt-get install libyaml-libyaml-perl` - but you'd need root access.